# How to create a query in Symfony using Doctrine extracting data from three related tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three tables:

```
users(id, firstName, lastName)
user_role(userId, roleId)
roles(id, role, userId)
```

I have also the respective entities based on these tables, generated in Symfony:

```
users (id, firstName, lastName, user_role[])
user_role (users, roles)
roles (id, role)
```

When I make the following query, it works correctly:

```
public function getAllUsers() {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
              SELECT users_.firstName FROM MyApp:users users_
        ');
        $result = $query->getArrayResult();
        dump($result);
    }



Result:



 array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "firstName" => "Paul"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "firstName" => "John"
  ]
]
```

But when I what to join the Entities users JOIN user_roles JOIN roles,
the result is the following:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
              SELECT users_.firstName, r.role FROM MyApp:users users_
              JOIN users_.user_role ur
              JOIN  ur.roles r
        ');
        $result = $query->getArrayResult();
        dump($result);

Result:

    array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "firstName" => "Paul"
    "role" => "admin"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "firstName" => "Paul"
    "role" => "user"
  ]
]
```

As it should be:

```
array:2 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "firstName" => "Paul"
        "role" => "admin"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "firstName" => "John"
        "role" => "user"
      ]
    ]
```

Where am I wrong?
How can I make it correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do it like this? If you use what Symfony and Doctrine provide to you, all you have to do is tell it is a `ManyToMany` relation between User and Role, then you can fetch users (eager loading of roles should result in a join, otherwise just do something long the lines of `->join('u.roles', r')`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all i recommend using the QueryBuilder (like proposed by Kero) for simple tasks like this to minimize the amount of syntax errors in the query itself ;

```
$query = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('u.name name', 'r.role role')
    ->from(User::class, 'u')
    ->join('u.user_role', 'ur')
    ->join('ur.role', 'r')
    ->getQuery();

$result = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

If the data outputted is incorrect I dare to bet the data in your database is likewise incorrect and the problem lies somewhere else.

Secondly, its also a bit strange you have the 'UserRole' entity (I suppose ,otherwise you would not need to join it in the query), Doctrine should handle many-to-many relations and its link tables by itself, or am I missing something ?